# How to log all Windows command line output? (not asking about redirection)

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there some reasonably simple way to log *all* output from the Windows 10 command line to a file?

I'm not asking about tee or >, >> on each specific command (I know about those).

I want a log of the *entire* interactive command line session - everything that appears on the screen.

Comment: *conemu* (replacement terminal) can do this.